# Data is not appearing inside Kendo Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC App with Kendo Grid control. For some reason, I am unable to get the data inside the grid when the page loads.

I think I am doing something wrong in the order of Kendo JS files reference order.

And when I click the grid refresh icon on the bottom right, it pulls the data in the GET mode and renders it in the entire page as JSON.

[image]

View Code::-

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/Kendo/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>

<link href="~/Content/Kendo/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/Kendo/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/Kendo/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/Kendo/kendo.dataviz.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/Kendo/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/Kendo/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<h2>Demo with Kendo Grid Sample</h2>
<br />

<div>
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<GetUserDataSet_Result>()
                      .Name("userGrid")
                      .Columns(columns =>
                      {
                          columns.Bound(p => p.ID).Title("ID");
                          columns.Bound(p => p.FirstName).Title("First Name");
                          columns.Bound(p => p.LastName).Title("Last Name");
                      })
                      .Pageable(pager => pager.Enabled(true).Refresh(true).PageSizes(new List<object> { 10, 20, 50, "all" }))
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                            .Ajax()
                            .ServerOperation(true)
                            .PageSize(15)
                            .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ID))
                            .Read(read => read.Action("UserData", "Home"))
                      )
    )

</div>
```

Controller Code::-

```
  public ActionResult About()
        {
            //ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";            
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult UserData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            MyCloudRepoEntities mx = new my_Nitro_Demo.MyCloudRepoEntities();
            List<GetUserDataSet_Result> lstUserData = mx.GetUserDataSet().ToList();

            return Json(lstUserData.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Do you see any javascript errors when you open developer tools in your browser?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem lies in the order of javascript references & i was referring them in the bottom of the webpage. So i moved the script references to the top of the page and in the below order. And the problem got fixed.

```
<script src="/my-Nitro/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>  
<script src="/my-Nitro/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="/my-Nitro/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: if you check this bit of the API documentation it shows you how to `defer` the initialisation of the scripts http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/fundamentals#configuration-Deferred

Answer (score 0):

Please add a **AutoBind** for your grid to bind on load.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<GetUserDataSet_Result>()
.AutoBind(true)
.Name("userGrid")
//code continues......
```